# Communication error between jsp and servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

There is a dropdown list in my jsp page in which there are several websites name e.g google.com etc.
And there is a textbox which is used as a keyword search.

Also there is a servlet file which is used for webcrwaling.
now when i select any of the url from dropdown then it shoukd connect to the servlet then retrive a links of that particular keyword.
how to achieve this pls help..

.jsp file

```
<%@ page 
import="java.sql.*" 
%>
<%ResultSet rs=null; %>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
    Select website name from DropdownList
</title>
 <link href="Desktop/style.css"  rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css" />
        </head>
<body bgcolor="8B4513">
<%

    Connection conn=null;
    try
    {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection

("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tendermysql","root","root");
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Record");



%>

<form  action ="Search.java"   method="post">
<center>
<h1> Welcome to Ezest Tender Optimzed Search</h1>
Choose Website: 

<select  name ="URL" >
<%
 while(rs.next())
    {
        %>
    <option   value="<%=rs.getString(3) %>">
    <% out.println(rs.getString(3)); %>
    </option>
   <% } %>
    </select>
  <% }
   catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Wrong Input" +e);
    } 

  %>
<br>
 Enter Keyword:
<input Type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

.java file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class Search extends HttpServlet 
   {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static DB db = new DB();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 

  {

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();



        try {
            db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Record;");
        } catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         try {
            processPage("http://www.mit.edu", out);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

  public static void    processPage(String URL, PrintWriter out)
  throws SQLException, IOException
    {       

        //check if the given URL is already in database
        String sql = "select * from Record where URL_Link = '"+URL+"'";
        ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
        if(rs.next())

        {

        }
        else
        {
            //store the URL to database to avoid parsing again
            sql = "INSERT INTO  `tenderMysql`.`Record` " + "(`URL_Link`) 
            VALUES " + "(?);";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement
            (sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1,URL);
            stmt.execute();

            //get useful information
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mit.edu").get();

            if(doc.text().contains("education"))
            {
                out.println ("<a href='" +URL+ "'>"+URL+"</a>" );  

            }

            else
            {
                out.println("There are no content");
            }
            out.println("<br/>");
            out.println("<br/>");
            //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
            Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link: questions){
                if(link.attr("href").contains("mit.edu"))
                    processPage(link.attr("abs:href"),out);


        }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: so at what part you are stuck?

Comment: What is your concrete question? Do you want us to write everything for you? Do you want us to guess, in the wall of code you posted, what could be the problem(s)? Tell us preciesly what you expect this code to do and what it does instead. Post any relevant error message.

Comment: So you need to execute servlet when you select option from the select option. i am correct??

Comment: @pratik sir,  yes u are correct...

Comment: in that case you need to call servlet onchange of Select option.

Comment: @JBNizet sir,   actually i want a links from that selected DropDown list of a related Keyword...        
but i hardcoded it in  a servlet file.

Comment: Can u give me a sample code for that Pratik sir

Answer (score 0):

Here you can take a dummy form.
And then on a change of select you can call function and submit a form using javascript.

HTML

```
    <select  name ="URL" onchange="SubmitCall('<%=rs.getString(3) %>')">
    <%
     while(rs.next())
        {
            %>
        <option   value="<%=rs.getString(3) %>">
        <% out.println(rs.getString(3)); %>
        </option>
       <% } %>
        </select>
      <% }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println("Wrong Input" +e);
        } 

      %>
<form action="Search" id="searchForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url">
</from>
```

javaScript

```
 function SubmitCall(valueObj){
        //Set in hidden field
        $("#url").val(valueObj);
        $("#Search").submit();

        //Using ajax
        $.ajax({url: "Search", 
                data: $("#url").val(valueObj),
                success: function(result){
                   alert(data);
                }
        });    
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74576/discussion-on-answer-by-pratik-communication-error-between-jsp-and-servlet).

Answer (score 0):

according to you  this is my jsp file...

```
<form action="Search" id="searchForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url">

<center>
 <h1> Welcome to Ezest Tender Optimzed Search</h1>
Choose Website: 

  <select  name ="URL" onchange="SubmitCall('<%=rs.getString(2) %>')">
    <%
     while(rs.next())
        {
            %>
        <option   value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>">
        <% out.println(rs.getString(2)); %>
        </option>

       <% } %>
        </select>

      <% }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println("Wrong Input" +e);
        } 

      %>
    <script>
      function SubmitCall(valueObj)
      {
            //Set in hidden field
            $("#url").val(valueObj);
            $("#Search").submit();
        }
      </script>  
</center>    
</form>    
</body>     
</html>
```

And below is my java file...

```
        public static void  processPage(String URL, PrintWriter out) 
        throws SQLException, IOException
    {       

        //check if the given URL is already in database
        String sql = "select * from Record where URL_Link = '"+URL+"'";
        ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
        if(rs.next())

        {

        }
        else
        {
            //store the URL to database to avoid parsing again
            sql = "INSERT INTO  `tenderMysql`.`Record` " + "
                (`URL_Link`) VALUES " + "(?);";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement
            (sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1,URL);
            stmt.execute();

            //get useful information
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("Link").get();

            if(doc.text().contains("education"))
            {
                out.println ("<p>'" +URL+ "'>"+URL+"</p>" );  

            }

            else
            {
                out.println("There are no content");
            }
            out.println("<br/>");
            out.println("<br/>");
            //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
            Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link: questions){
                if(link.attr("href").contains("mit.edu"))
                    processPage(link.attr("abs:href"),out);


        }
        }
    }
}
```